file lost in /run/user/1000/doc
Have worked with qelectrotech which installed as snap on ubuntu 20.04
A couple of times it worked creating and updating files. Now after restart it can't find recent files. They are in /run/user/1000/doc/ and than some uuid. I still see the files but can't open or copy them.
Any one know's for what is /run/user/1000/doc and why there is a special file handling ?
How could I get out the file ?

/run is usually a memory based filesystem; anything created here is lost when your system reboots. That's expected behavior and typical across most distributions. Sounds like a buggy application if it expects things created in /run to persist.

what a mess. Thanks letting me know @larsks
